# C++ template and ambiguous function call

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguous-call

Some code I have no control over has a number of overloaded functions which accepts different types

i.e.

```
setValue(int)
setValue(std::string)
setValue(bool)
```

And I have a template function which would idealy take any one of these types and pass it on to the correct setValue function.

```
template <class T>
do_something(T value) {
    ...
    setValue(value);
```

But I get this error

```
error: call to member function 'SetValue' is ambiguous
```

Is there anything I can do to work around this problem without copy and pasting my code for each type like the writers of setValue have?

Comment: What type are you trying to instantiate your template for? Most likely it's a type that there isn't an *exact* match in the overloaded functions but more than one valid conversion

Comment: Did you tried `::setValue((T)value);`?

Comment: For example `char` would be as ambiguous as it can get :)

Comment: @jcoder You were exactly right, thank you very much.

Comment: @k06a awful suggestion. You could at least suggest static_cast<T>(value)

Comment: @user2675345 could you show us how do you call `do_something`? which type is ambiguous?

Comment: @billz In by answer, I show a case: `setValue(char); setValue(double);` and `do_something<int>()` is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by defining you own SetValue with exact match and forwarding to the correct overload.

```
void setValue(int i) { setValue(static_cast<double>(i)) }
```

or (if you have a lot of "setValue" functions with same type) you may help the compiler to choose which overload to use like this:

```
void setValue(char a);
void setValue(double a);

template <typename T>
struct TypeToUseFor
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <>
struct TypeToUseFor<int>
{
    typedef double type;
};

template <class T>
void func(T value)
{
    setValue(static_cast<typename TypeToUseFor<T>::type>(value));
//    setValue(value);
}

int main() {
    func(0);   // int -> ?
    func('0'); // exact match
    func(0.0); // exect match
    func(0.f); // float -> double

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems with:

```
void setValue(int a)
{
}

void setValue(std::string a)
{
}

void setValue(bool a)
{
}

template <class T>
void func(T value)
{
    setValue(value);
}

int main()
{
    func(5);
}
```

Here is my run: http://codepad.org/1wq8qd7l

Comment: Yes there are no problems with this logic. It seems my problem was something slightly different.